# Share image from UWP app failed when deployed from store

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Cannot figure what is goind on.Tried both:

`StorageFile thumbnailFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\foo.png");`

`StorageFile thumbnailFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/foo.png"));`

with foo.png tagged as **Content**.

Works **very well** inside visual studio (debug AND release), as well when running app deployed by visual studio.

But if I create package and manually install using powershell script I get a suspicious **FileNotFoundException**.

Could someone explain what's going on...?

Comment: I built a sample and tried to reproduce your problem. However, it works well in my side. So could you share [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Sorry for the delay. Sample available on [Github](https://github.com/Aszan/Stack_35999610). Using StoreLogo.scale-100.png highlights the failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is related to the `StoreLogo.scale-100.png` you've wanted to retrieve.

When we create an app package with **[App bundles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-package-requirements#app-bundles)**, it will generate multiple package for different language-specific and image-scale assets.

> For apps that target Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1, and later, Visual Studio can generate an app bundle (.appxbundle) to reduce the size of the app that users download. This can be helpful if you've defined language-specific assets, a variety of image-scale assets, or resources that apply to specific versions of Microsoft DirectX.
>
> With an app bundle, a user will only download the relevant files, rather than all possible resources.

After manually install the app with PowerShell, we can find the app in **"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"**. For your sample, the packages may like following:
[image]

In the Assets folder of the main package, it contains following image:
[image]

The `StoreLogo.scale-100.png` is under the **scale-100** satellite app package:
[image]

This is because the main app package contains resources for whatever the default scale is. And

> The default asset scale for Universal Windows apps is 200. (See: [Migrate apps to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx))

If we use `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path` to get the installed path, we will find it returns the main app package's path like:

> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\2c33274f-13c1-47cf-a1e6-f64a5175e8e5_1.0.6.0_x64__9wkhgz7fyfewr.

So when you use  `StorageFile thumbnailFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\StoreLogo.scale-100.png");` to retrieve `StoreLogo.scale-100.png`, you will get `FileNotFoundException` as it's not under the folder.

As a workaround, we can remove the qualifier in `StoreLogo.scale-100.png` and change its name to something else so it can be included in main app package. Or we can set **"Generate app bundle"** to **"Never"** to avoid generating image-scale satellite app package like:
[image]

If you do need to use image-scale assets and want get the benefit of app bundles, you can try use **[Resource Management System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx)** to retrieve the specific scale image.

> The **[ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcemanager.aspx)** not only supports access to an app's string resources, but it maintains the ability to enumerate and inspect the various file resources as well. In order to avoid collisions between files and other resources that originate from within a file, indexed file paths all reside within a reserved "Files" **[ResourceMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcemap.aspx)** subtree. For example, the file images/logo.png corresponds to the resource name Files/images/Logo.png.
>
> The **[StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx)** APIs transparently handle references to files as resources and are appropriate for typical usage scenarios. The **[ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcemanager.aspx)** should only be used for advanced scenarios, such as overridden context or enumeration of possible values.

So we can retrieve the specific scale image like following:

```
ResourceMap resMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Files");
var resourceContext = new ResourceContext();
resourceContext.QualifierValues["scale"] = "100";
StorageFile thumbnailFile = await resMap.GetValue("Assets/StoreLogo.png", resourceContext).GetValueAsFileAsync();
```

Comment: Big thanks for your deep response & your time. I reached the conclusion that this specific file was the issue and solved the problem with my app a few days ago by using another one. I understand what you explained. Remaining issue is the fact that this doesn't occur in VS or when app is deployed via VS. So we just have to be careful about this. Anyway I appreciate you take time to clearly explain what happens behind the hood. Great answer :)

Comment: Yeah, this issue only happens when generating app bundle. Usually, we won't retrieve a image with specific scale. The language or scale will be chose automatically by system according to the environment. If we want to get some specific resources, [**Resource Management System**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx) is the right way to go.